# Entity validation - either zero or at least three

Tags: symfony, validation, symfony-validator

I'm using symfony 2.8 version and I have encountered a following problem. I want my field 'seeAlso' of entity 'Article' to be restricted to have either zero (none) or at least 3 objects (another articles). So I have these in my yaml validation:

```
seeAlso:
 - Count:
   min: 3
   minMessage: 'you have got to pick zero or at least three articles'
```

It checks if it is less than three well, but it does not allow me to let the field be empty. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define a custom validation. You can proceed in two ways

## 1 Create a custom validation constraint

First of all you need to create a constraint class

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ConstraintZeroOrAtLeastThreeConstraint extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Put here a validation error message';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return get_class($this).'Validator';
    }
}
```

Here you have defined a constraint with a message and you're telling to symfony which is the validator (that we're going to define below)

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class ZeroOrAtLeastThreeConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!count($value)) {
            return;
        }

        if (count($value) >= 3) {
            return;
        }

        $this
          ->context
          ->buildValidation('You should choose zero or at least three elements')
          ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

Now you can use your validator upon the property by annotating it with `@ ConstraintZeroOrAtLeastThreeConstraint` (that of course you have to import in entity file in order to use)

Of course you can even customize the values 0 and 3 to generalize this constraint into `ZeroOrAtLeastTimesConstraint` by using

```
public function __construct($options)
{
    if (!isset($options['atLeastTimes'])) {
        throw new MissingOptionException(...);
    }

    $this->atLeastTimes = $options['atLeastTimes'];
}
```

## 2 Create a callback validation function inside the entity

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
{
    if (!count($this->getArticles()) {
       return;
    }

    if (count($this->getArticles() >= 3) { 
       return;
    }

    $context
      ->buildViolation('You should choose 0 or at least 3 articles')
      ->addViolation();
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use your first method and I have questions: 1. where do I store the constraint class? 2. where do I store the validator? (second file) 3. how do I use this validator in my property? 3. what then should be put in my yml file?

Comment: @user7808407 Answers 1 and 2: where you prefer, usually under `Validator\Constraint` the constraint and `Validator` the `Validator`. Answer 3: In your `yml` file you can use it like any other constraint

Comment: thanks for clarifying. So I followed all steps and got this error message     Constraint validator "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\ConstraintSeeAlsoConstraintValidator" does not exist or it is not enabled. Check the "validatedBy" method in your constraint class "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\ConstraintSeeAlsoConstraint" What can be wrong?

Comment: @user7808407 You should import it with a `use` and the correct FQCN. Your answer is there; this is no more related to symfony but to PHP in general :)

Comment: I understand that, and thank you very for much for the help, but I can't seem to make it work by `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\ConstraintSeeAlsoConstraint;` and `/* * @ConstraintSeeAlsoConstraint;*/private $seeAlso;` .

Comment: I finally put it to work, DonCallisto's answer is very helpful. By the way, both files should be put into the \Validator\Constraints, which helped me a lot

Comment: @user7808407 no, that's not necessary: my advice is that you should study PHP a little bit :)